# how do you call a method from a different file in java?

Tags: java, class, methods

here are my two files:
file 1:

```
 public class Step2 {
       public static void main(String[] args) {
        output("-STEP 2-");lineBreak();


        int size = inputINT("How many smart devices do you have: ");

        SmartHome[] sh = new SmartHome[size];

        for(int i = 0;i<size;i++){
                SmartDevice insertValues = new SmartDevice(inputSTR(
                        "Device name " + (i+1)),
                        inputDBL("Device location " + (i+1)),
                        inputBLN("Device status " + (i+1)));
                        insertDevice(insertValues);            


        }
```

file 2:

```
    public class SmartHome {

    private SmartDevice[] smartDevices;

    public SmartHome(int size){

        SmartDevice[] smartDevices = new SmartDevice[size];
    }
    public SmartHome(SmartDevice[] sd){enter code here
        smartDevices = sd;

    }


    public void insertDevice(SmartDevice device){


        for (int i=0;i<smartDevices.length;i++) { 
        if (smartDevices[i] == null) 
            smartDevices[i] = device;
            break;    
        }
    }
```

(These two files are in the same project)
When I try to use call the insertDevice method I am given the problem that "cannot find symbol" and I am unsure why. I have tried calling other methods that exist inside file 2 however I get the same problem, therefore, it seems as if the compiler is looking in the wrong place?
Please help

Comment: you have to call it through an instance of the class. It's basic OO

Comment: Also, it looks like you want to create a single home with `size` smart devices, not an array of `size` SmartHomes. So pass the constructor argument: `SmartHome sh = new SmartHome(size);`

Comment: a Java method can't be called from a file

Comment: @fantaghirocco MyClass.java is a file. Of course it can be. The OP just means that both classes are in different .java files.

Answer (score 0):

well, you are creating array of objects `sh = new SmartHome` so to you can call methods within objects by simply `sh[index].insertDevice(device);`